# AWS ec2 git error after installing firefox

Tags: git, firefox, amazon-ec2, gtk

I was trying to install firefox (headless mode) on an aws ec2 instance to run selenium test.
As aws ec2 linux doesn’t come with Gtk libraries, I had to install them manually, I used this script https://gist.github.com/joekiller/4144838 to install firefox and its dependencies.

It installed firefox but now my I am facing issues with Git.
When I run any git command, I am getting the following error:

git-remote-https: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libnsssysinit.so: undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure

I tried googling it but couldn’t find any resolution of this issue.
It will be really helpful if somebody who has worked on running selenium tests or have seen similar issue with firefox/git on aws ec2 linux can help me with this.